# "excel has stopped working" while vba code is running

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

when I run my vba code by clicking on a command button, "excel has stopped working" keep appearing and the application crashes. I had tried to figure out where the problem is coming from, by pressing F8 but the error didn't show up.

Here are some conditions of my workbook:

worksheets are not visible because a userform is covering the hole screen. it will disappear just with using a password.

The error will appear when ever I click on the command button to run the code but there are 2 exceptions:

1. when I edit my code (even irrelevant changes), the code will work fine just for 1 time, and then the error appears again for the next time.
2. when I use the password and run the user form manually or when I debug it with F8 key

```
Sub price_rep2()
Unload price_rep_frm


ok = False
For kl = 7 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(9).Range("B:B")) + 5
    If Sheets(9).Range("B" & kl) = Sheets(1).Range("B" & Label44.Caption) Then
        ok = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next kl
If ok = False Then
    f = MsgBox("error", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "error")
    Exit Sub
End If

If Sheets(5).Range("A6") > 10 Then
    uandme = MsgBox("error", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "error")
    Exit Sub
Else
    Sheets(5).Range("A6") = Sheets(5).Range("A6") + 1
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

Sheets(8).Range("C2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ12")
Sheets(8).Range("D2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ45")
Sheets(8).Range("E2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ46")
Sheets(8).Range("F2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ47")
Sheets(8).Range("G2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ48")
Sheets(8).Range("H2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ49")
Sheets(8).Range("I2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ50")
Sheets(8).Range("J2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ51")
Sheets(8).Range("K2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ60")
Sheets(8).Range("L2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ52")
Sheets(8).Range("M2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ53")
Sheets(8).Range("N2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ54")
Sheets(8).Range("O2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ55")
Sheets(8).Range("P2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ56")
Sheets(8).Range("Q2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ57")
Sheets(8).Range("R2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ58")
Sheets(8).Range("S2") = Sheets(5).Range("KQ59")
radif = 3
finded = False
For i = 7 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(9).Range("B:B")) + 5
    If Sheets(9).Range("B" & i) = Sheets(1).Range("B" & Label44.Caption) And Sheets(9).Range("D" & i) = ComboBox1.Text Then
        Sheets(8).Range("C" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("C" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("D" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("D" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("F" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("E" & i) * Sheets(9).Range("F" & i) * (Sheets(9).Range("G" & i))
        Sheets(8).Range("G" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("H" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("H" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("I" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("I" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("J" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("J" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("K" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("K" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("R" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("L" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("L" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("M" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("M" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("N" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("N" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("O" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("O" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("P" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("P" & i)
        Sheets(8).Range("Q" & radif) = Sheets(9).Range("Q" & i)
        finded = True
        radif = radif + 1
    End If
Next i
If finded = False Then
    Exit Sub
End If


For kl = 7 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(3).Range("B:B")) + 5
    If Sheets(3).Range("D" & kl) = ComboBox1.Text And Sheets(3).Range("B" & kl) = Sheets(1).Range("B" & Label44.Caption) Then
        sabt = False
        mat_tot = 0
        For ko = 3 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(8).Range("C:C")) + 1
            If Sheets(8).Range("C" & ko) = Sheets(2).Range("C" & (Sheets(3).Range("C" & kl))) Then

                If Sheets(3).Range("AI" & kl) = Sheets(5).Range("KG3") Or Sheets(3).Range("AI" & kl) = Sheets(5).Range("KG6") Then
                    For ki = 9 To 25 Step 2
                        If Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki) = material_insert_frm.Label79.Caption Or Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki) = material_insert_frm.Label540.Caption Then
                            If Sheets(3).Range("AC" & kl) <> "" Then
                                mat_tot = mat_tot + (Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1) * (1 + Sheets(3).Range("AC" & kl)))
                            Else
                                mat_tot = mat_tot + (Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1))
                            End If
                            sabt = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next ki


                ElseIf Sheets(3).Range("AI" & kl) = Sheets(5).Range("KG4") Then
                    For ki = 9 To 25 Step 2
                        If Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki) = material_insert_frm.Label75.Caption Then
                            For ku = 9 To 25 Step 2
                                If Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ku) = material_insert_frm.Label76.Caption Then
                                    If Sheets(3).Range("AC" & kl) <> "" Then
                                        mat_tot = mat_tot + ((((Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ku + 1) * Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1)) * (1 + Sheets(3).Range("AC" & kl))) / 1000000))
                                    Else
                                        mat_tot = mat_tot + (((Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ku + 1) * Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1)) / 1000000))
                                    End If
                                    sabt = True
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next ku
                        End If
                        If sabt = True Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next ki


                ElseIf Sheets(3).Range("AI" & kl) = Sheets(5).Range("KG5") Then
                    For ki = 9 To 25 Step 2
                        If Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki) = material_insert_frm.Label75.Caption Then
                            If Sheets(3).Range("AC" & kl) <> "" Then
                                mat_tot = mat_tot + (((Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1) * (1 + Sheets(3).Range("AC" & kl)))))
                            Else
                                mat_tot = mat_tot + ((Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1)))
                            End If
                            sabt = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next ki


                ElseIf Sheets(3).Range("E" & kl) = Sheets(5).Range("KO9") Then
                    For ki = 9 To 25 Step 2
                        If Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki) = material_insert_frm.Label487.Caption Then
                            If Sheets(3).Range("AC" & kl) <> "" Then
                                mat_tot = mat_tot + ((((Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1) * (1 + Sheets(3).Range("AC" & kl)))) * Sheets(2).Range("F" & (Sheets(3).Range("C" & kl)))) / 1000)
                            Else
                                mat_tot = mat_tot + (((Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1)) / 1000))
                            End If
                            sabt = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next ki


                ElseIf Sheets(3).Range("E" & kl) = Sheets(5).Range("KO13") Then
                    For ki = 9 To 25 Step 2
                        If Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki) = material_insert_frm.Label75.Caption Then
                            For ku = 9 To 25 Step 2
                                If Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ku) = material_insert_frm.Label76.Caption Then
                                    For kou = 9 To 25 Step 2
                                        If Sheets(3).Cells(kl, kou) = material_insert_frm.Label415.Caption Then
                                            If Sheets(3).Range("AC" & kl) <> "" Then
                                                mat_tot = mat_tot + (((Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ku + 1) / 1000 * Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1) / 1000 * 4) + (Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1) / 1000 * Sheets(3).Cells(kl, kou + 1) / 1000 * 2) + (Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ku + 1) / 1000 * Sheets(3).Cells(kl, kou + 1) / 1000 * 2)) * (1 + Sheets(3).Range("AC" & kl)))
                                            Else
                                                mat_tot = mat_tot + (((Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ku + 1) / 1000 * Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1) / 1000 * 4) + (Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ki + 1) / 1000 * Sheets(3).Cells(kl, kou + 1) / 1000 * 2) + (Sheets(3).Cells(kl, ku + 1) / 1000 * Sheets(3).Cells(kl, kou + 1) / 1000 * 2)))
                                            End If
                                            sabt = True
                                            Exit For
                                        End If
                                    Next kou
                                End If
                                If sabt = True Then
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            Next ku
                        End If
                        If sabt = True Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next ki
                End If

                If Sheets(3).Range("H" & kl) <> Sheets(5).Range("KO15") Then
                    kode_anbar = True
                Else
                    kode_anbar = False
                End If

                If kode_anbar = True Then
                    For i = 3 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(5).Range("KU2:KU1000000")) + 1
                        If Sheets(3).Range("H" & kl) = Sheets(5).Range("KU" & i) Then
                            Sheets(8).Range("E" & ko) = Sheets(8).Range("E" & ko) + (mat_tot * Sheets(5).Range("LA" & i))
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next i
                    Exit For
                Else

                    If Sheets(3).Range("AD" & kl) <> "" Then
                        Sheets(8).Range("E" & ko) = Sheets(8).Range("E" & ko) + (mat_tot * Sheets(3).Range("AD" & kl))
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next ko
    End If
Next kl


Sheets(1).Range("A1") = 1
Unload Me
Unload start_frm
yy = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(8).Range("C:C")) + 1
Sheets(8).Range("C2:S" & yy).Select
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "B Nazanin"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
End With
Columns("C:S").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Sheets(8).Range("C2:S2").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Set x = ActiveWorkbook
nam = x.Path
Set y = Workbooks.Add
y.SaveAs Filename:=nam & "\price_rep2.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
x.Sheets(8).Copy before:=Workbooks("price_rep2.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
y.Close (True)
x.Close (True)
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question, exactly? That's a lot of code to look at, and no one can run it since we don't have the workbook(s) and their data. Put some Debug.Print lines in there so that you can determine what part of the code is failing.

Comment: I would suggest you to step through your code using the debugger by clicking anywhere inside the code and pressing F8 to run one line at the time. Then you'll be able to know which line makes Excel crash and it will be easier for us to help you ([More on debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)).

Comment: Actually I don't know  where the problem starts and I had tried to debug that by pressing F8 but as I said, the error will not appear as I run the code manualy.

Comment: Have you ran through the code entirely by pressing F8? Because I can imagine it can take a while with those nested loops. Furthermore, I would try to avoid "Select" methods, since this is almost never necessary. "Cells.Select" for instance selects all Cells in the workbook.

Comment: I think that was the problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot for your answers, the problem was using "select" in the code.